# What can be wrong in IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have successfully used IntentService a few times, but in the current app, I can't get BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() to start.  I have the exact String in Intent's action of the IntentService and in the IntentFilter which was registered in onResume along with the BroadcastReceiver.

```
    filter = new IntentFilter("com.currencyconverter2.intent.action.MESSAGE");
    Log.d("CC2", "intent filter created");
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    Log.d("CC2", "filter category added");
    receiver = new MessageReceiver();
    Log.d("CC2", "receiver instantiated");
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    Log.d("CC2", "receiver registered");
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    Log.d("CC2", "receiver unregistered");
}

public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.d(Tag, "entered onReceive...");
        String html = intent.getStringExtra("OUTPUT");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f4f36f"));
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }
}
```

I also specified the service in Manifest.xml.

```
<service android:name=".IntentServiceTest"></service>
```

My Log tells me that the intentBroadcast was broadcasted from the IntentService, and the app stopped there.  BroadcastReceiver didn't seem to have received it.  What can be wrong?  Thanks!

Edit:

My IntentService

```
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        Log.d(Tag, "setting intent action");
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.currencyconverter2.intent.action.MESSAGE");
        Log.d(Tag, "adding intent category");
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        Log.d(Tag, "putting intent extra");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("OUTPUT", data.text());
        Log.d(Tag, "sending broadcast");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.out.println("f");
    }
}

}
```

Edit 2:

Found the bug.

```
                          Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        Log.d(Tag, "setting intent action");
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.currencyconverter2.intent.action.MESSAGE");
        Log.d(Tag, "adding intent category");
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        Log.d(Tag, "putting intent extra");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("OUTPUT", data.text());
        Log.d(Tag, "sending broadcast");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I should have sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".MessageReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.currencyconverter2.intent.action.MESSAGE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

^-^

Comment: Still doesn't trigger the filter.  I put up my IntentService.  Do you see something wrong?

Comment: And I already registered the filter and receiver programmatically.  But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) use to do task and shut it out, But as par your code it seems u are using long running time, use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)